I Does Not Run my flutter project in VSCode IDE
In the meantime, I was able to my flutter projects well with VSCode IDE.
However, due to circumstances, I couldn't work on Flutter for a few months.
Then I came back and ran my project that was previously executed in VSCode, but it was not running.  Even if I press the "Start without debugging" button in the main.dart file and run it, the project does not run after only very short briefly showing the message "Starting debug session..." at the bottom of VSCode.
Even if you create a completely new counter default project and run it with no modification, the same message is poped up at the right bottom of VSCode  and then disappears, and the project does not run.
Worse still, I don't see any execution error messages in the problems window, in the output window, in the debug console window, and in the terminal window.
It's clean.
But if I run the command "flutter run" in the terminal window of VSCode, the project is running normally.
I also set the 'Path' environment variable for Windows to 'flutter/bin' normally.
My internet speed is very fast.
I remember that in the past, when I pressed the "Start without debugging" button in the main.dart file, the project ran.
Of course, if I run the command "flutter run" in the terminal window, the project will be executed, but it will be very cumbersome.
Is there a way to run the project by pressing the "Start without debugging" button on VSCode?
I have 1 regular Desktop Windows PC and 1 Windows laptop and both are showing the same phenomenon.
The flutter version of a regular PC is
Flutter 3.22.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 761747bfc5 (8 weeks ago) • 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
Engine • revision edd8546116
Tools • Dart 3.4.3 • DevTools 2.34.3.

The flutter version of the laptop is
Flutter 3.16.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 78666c8dc5 (7 months ago) • 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
Engine • revision 3f3e560236
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4.

My "settings.json" of VSCode:
{
   "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
   "github.gitAuthentication": false,
   "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
   "editor.wordWrapColumn": 90,
   "editor.formatOnSave": true,
   "editor.fontFamily": "\"JetBrains Mono\", \"Consolas\", \"Courier New\", monospace",
   "editor.fontLigatures": "calt",
   // "editor.fontSize": 11.5, // editor font 크기(JetBrains mono)
   "editor.fontSize": 12.2, // editor font 크기(JetBrains mono)
   "editor.tabSize": 3,
   "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
   "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
   "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true, // 괄호별 색상 적용 
   "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
   "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": true,
   "editor.linkedEditing": true,
   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll": "explicit"
   },
   "editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs": [],
   // "editor.renameOnType": true,
   "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
   "files.autoGuessEncoding": true,
   "workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs": true, // 파일 수정시 탭 색상 변경
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "tab.activeBackground": "#F0FFFF"
      // "tab.activeBackground": "#FAFAD2"
   },
   "[dart]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.formatOnType": true,
      "editor.rulers": [
         90
      ],
      "editor.selectionHighlight": true,
      "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
      "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
      "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
      "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off",
   },
   "dart.warnWhenEditingFilesOutsideWorkspace": false,
   "dart.renameFilesWithClasses": "prompt",
   "dart.previewFlutterUiGuides": true,
   "dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking": true,
   "dart.openDevTools": "flutter",
   "dart-data-class-generator.useEquatable": true,
   "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light Modern",
   "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
   "vs-kubernetes": {
      "vs-kubernetes.minikube-show-information-expiration": "2023-12-25T04:51:22.688Z"
   },
   "dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries": true,
   "dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
   "dart.flutterHotReloadOnSave": "allIfDirty",
   "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
   "dart.shareDevToolsWithFlutter": true,
} 

Where should I look to solve this problem?

You must create launch.json file in your .vscode folder
you can copy/paste this content (replace so_march by your project name)
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "so_march",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart", 
        },
        {
            "name": "so_march (profile mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "so_march (release mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "release"
        }
    ]
}


As you told me, I added "launch.json" to the project in VSCode and the project ran normally even when I pressed "Start without debugging" button in the main.dart file. Thank you.
But in the past, creating a flutter project at the terminal, 'opening' the flutter project in VSCode, selecting only the appropriate emulator device, and pressing the "Start without debugging" button in the main.dart file was sufficient, but has the VSCode's flutter operation changed recently?

Some VS Code extensions rely on launch.json to work properly. If you use specific extensions for Flutter or Dart, they may not behave as expected without this file.
